# Can't find C: drive using Ubuntu liveCD

Tags: windows, data-recovery, live-cd

I have encountered the "bootmgr is missing" error with my Windows 7 computer and I was not able to boot to Windows beforehand either. I am currently attempting to recover my files before I reformat the Windows OS on my C: drive. That said, I am booting from a USB using Ubuntu and am in the "trial" version (just trying it without installing it).

I do not see my hard drive or the drive that would presumably be my C: drive in Windows when I look through the devices. I am not sure where my files may be but I am fairly certain they have not been deleted or formatted over.

I am strictly looking for ways to recover the files to an external drive and not so much how to dual boot or permanently install Ubuntu.

Comment: Linux does not use C: to identify hard drives. It uses /dev/sda1 for example. Start gparted and take a look.

Comment: I understand that the hard drive will have a different name, but I wanted to convey which drive I was looking for in the best way I could.  I  may have identified the drive now but like I said below, when I try to open it, the entire window closes.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning letters to drives is the traditional way of addressing hard drives and partitions in the user interface for DOS, Windows and related operating systems. Other operating systems have different naming schemes:

- [What is the Linux drive naming scheme?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56929/40581) (Also read the answer by [Joel Coehoorn](https://askubuntu.com/a/56982/40581))

Usually, Ubuntu running in a live session environment is capable of mounting Microsoft filesystems like FAT and NTFS. The filesystems should be available for mounting in the filemanager or be automatically mounted already. It should be easy to find the right filesystem when they were **labeled** accordingly, otherwise you have to guess by size, remember the position of the partition in a partition manager or dumb trial an error. Typically external filesystems are mounted below `/media`.

In some cases you may no be able to mount a certain filesystem:

- [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/40581)
- Proprietary full disk encryption like Bitlocker with or without TPM.

  - Truecrypt volumes and system partitions with pre-boot authentication can be decrypted with Truecrypt for Linux or [dm-crypt](https://askubuntu.com/q/420749/40581).

Answer (score 0):

Your "C" drive will be located `/media/<possibly_a_long_series_of numbers>`

Use your file manager (Nautilus), go up(down) to root (`/`) and then into `/media`, and you will see it.

It is possible there might be ownership/permission problems in manipulating the files within this directory, or transferring them to an external, but just open it/them as root.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I may have found the folder but when I select it, the entire window closes and I go to blank desktop. Am I missing something? I am still a bit fuzzy on this whole "root" concept